# Every h-cobordism embeds into $M \times I$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, geometric-topology

Suppose we are in high dimension. By the s-cobordism theorem, any h-cobordism has an inverse given by a h-cobordism with the inverse torsion. Thus we have a isomorphism from the composite to the trivial h-cobordism. Thus by, restriction we can embed our h-cobordism into $M \times I$.

Is there a simple handle manipulation argument that doesn't use the full force of the s-cobordism theorem? Does it work in low dimensions?

Comment: You cannot always achieve an inverse h-cobordism by flipping the cobordism around. Note that for an h-cobordism $(W, M, N)$, we have $\tau(W, M) = (-1)^{\text{dim}(M)} \overline{\tau(W, N)}$ for an invoultion bar coming from a twisted involution on $\mathbb{Z}[\pi_1]$, see e.g. the Surgery Book by Crowley, Lück and Macko.
The s-cobordism theorem says that there is an h-cobordism $W'$ over $N$ with torsion $-\tau(W,M)$ and this $W'$ does the job.

Comment: Ahh, thank you for the correction

Comment: I’ve edited to take that into account.